How to fix android emulator UI scale?
I tried to add Pixel Fold and got a problem with it's UI resolution that I can't figure out how to fix and scale to normal resolution. There's might be an easy google request for the solution, but I've got answers only on general device scale, so please, don't blame me if I didn't find solution. If someone know how to fix it, please, share your advice

